# Why not working angular js ajax when $http.get use in this code?

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("mymodule",[]);

app.controller("employeeController",function($scope,$http){
    var url ="data/records.json";

    $http.get(url).success(function(response){
        $scope.employees =response;

    });

});
```

Comment: So what doesnt work? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: `.success` has been deprecated.. and do use `response.data`

Comment: What is the output of response? (i.e. `console.log(response);`)

Comment: Thanks. its working

Comment: @KhairulIslamTonmoy you checked the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You should access `response.data`,also replace success with then,**`.success`** has been deprecated.

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
        $scope.employees =response.data;
});
```

Comment: You should also be using `.then()` instead of `.success()`

Answer (score 1):

`.success` is deprecated since angular version 1.4 To catch the promise you can  use `then`.

Note that response of the `then` return data inside the data property. so you need to access the data property of that response.

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
        $scope.employees =response.data
});
```

Comment: That is inaccurate. The `.success` method was deprecated in version 1.4,  removable by configuration in version 1.5, and completely removed in version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
app.controller("paymentRequestController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        
        $scope.payment_method_info = [];
        $scope.rate = 0;
        $scope.getPaymentInfo = function () {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
            }).success(function (response) {
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    $scope.rate = response[0].rate;
                    $scope.payment_method_info = response;
                } else {
                    $scope.rate = 0;
                    $scope.payment_method_info = [];
                }
            });
        };
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't have enought reputation. i want to add on @Jayanta reply
this is another syntax:

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deffered.resolve(data);
```

so when you try to add "data" to console.log(data) it will dislay the right data.

Comment: i am sorry sir, i think you are using the angular version less then 1.6 and the code have some syntax error. the code is traditional way and the success and error method is not working in 1.6 version.